# What have I missed? Simple HTML and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Why is this simple HTML document not working right? What have I missed? I got this solution in another thread but I can't get a hold of the person who submited it. All I've done is copied the parts he gave me from this: http://jsfiddle.net/UnQMU/

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function cancelBubleEv(e)
        {
             e = e||event;
             e.stopPropagation? e.stopPropagation() : e.cancelBubble = true;

        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).click(function () {

                $("#exampleDiv").hide();

            });
            $(".testColor").click(function (e) {
                $("#exampleDiv").toggle();
                cancelBubleEv(e);
            });
           $("#exampleDiv").click(function (e) {
                cancelBubleEv(e);
            });

        });​

    </script>

    <style type="text/css">

        #exampleDiv 
        {
            position: absolute;
            top:22px;
            left: 0px;
            width:198px;
            height:150px;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            border: 1px solid #7F9DB9;
            display: none;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div style="position:relative;">
        <div ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" width="200" class="testColor">
            Choose Multiple
        </div>
        <div id="exampleDiv">
            <input type="checkbox" ID="CheckBox2"/>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" ID="CheckBox3"/>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" ID="CheckBox4"/>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" ID="CheckBox5"/>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" ID="CheckBox6" runat="server" />
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" ID="CheckBox7"/>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" ID="CheckBox8"/>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" ID="CheckBox9"/>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" ID="CheckBox10"/>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" ID="CheckBox11"/>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" ID="CheckBox12"/>
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>​

</body>
```

Comment: Why would you choose to use such an old version of jQuery?  There is already version 1.7.2....

Comment: jQuery does everything that your cancelling function does. Just call stopPropagation.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm new to jQuery. Besides since none of the events are firing that has got to be the first problem to solve, right? The code itself is working.

Comment: It works fine on jsFiddle, even if I copy your code directly there. What does not work, and is there any error do you get?

Comment: You haven't said what you actual want the code to do. so how can we say what's wrong? It does toggle the element, what else where you expecting?

Comment: I know that the code is working on jsFiddle, that's what I wrote at the top. The problem is why isn't the code I pasted working? Try copying it to a new html document and you'll see that the events aren't fired the way they are on the jsFiddle page.

Comment: @Peter Saverman: It seems like the jsFiddle source has some weird unicode characters added. If I remove them it works. My apologies.

Comment: @atmd I expect it to do exactly what it does on the jsFiddle page. But as I just wrote, try copying the code I've pasted here into a new html document and you'll see that the element isn't toggling. To put my question this way: what is missing in my code that is perhaps hidden in the jsFiddle code? Why isn't mine working when I've pasted exactly the same code to my code on this page?

Comment: @pimvdb Is that unicode on my submited code as well?

Comment: Yes, after the last JavaScript semicolon there is one for example, which makes for a syntax error. Not sure why jsFiddle does this, but you can easily spot them if you copy the code into an editor.

Comment: @pimvdb That did the trick! Thanks a million!! How do I mark your comment as a right answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seemed to be that jsFiddle adds some unnoticeable characters to the source. If they are removed the code works. Note that the `cancelBubleEv` function is not necessary with jQuery, and why not use the latest version. There is no `</html>` either.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).click(function () {
                $("#exampleDiv").hide();
            });

            $(".testColor").click(function (e) {
                $("#exampleDiv").toggle();
                e.stopPropagation();
            });

            $("#exampleDiv").click(function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        #exampleDiv
        {
            position: absolute;
            top:22px;
            left: 0px;
            width:198px;
            height:150px;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            border: 1px solid #7F9DB9;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div style="position:relative;">
        <div ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" width="200" class="testColor">
            Choose Multiple
        </div>
        <div id="exampleDiv">
            <input type="checkbox" ID="CheckBox2"/>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" ID="CheckBox3"/>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" ID="CheckBox4"/>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" ID="CheckBox5"/>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" ID="CheckBox6" runat="server" />
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" ID="CheckBox7"/>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" ID="CheckBox8"/>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" ID="CheckBox9"/>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" ID="CheckBox10"/>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" ID="CheckBox11"/>
            <br />
            <input type="checkbox" ID="CheckBox12"/>
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks again! You've been of great help!